# Newbie query: how do I match combined selectors with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've sussed how to use YQL and jquery to pull in and inject HTML into a div element.

However, I want to filter out a div with the class in the HTML "region and-channel cl". I've been able to understand how to pick up single selectors, and multiple selectors using commas. What about compounded selectors like this?

Here's an example page with the selectors included http://www.thisisstaffordshire.co.uk/news

Kind regards

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all the selectors together without any space

```
$(".region.and-channel.cl")
```